# User folder access when dual booting Win7 & Win8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, ntfs, multi-boot

I've got Win7 & Win8 in a dual boot configuration.  When I try to access my Win7 User folder from Win8 I get permission errors.  I understand that my user accounts in Win7 & Win8 have unique SIDs and this is causing the issue.

What I am not clear on is how to ***safely*** configure the Win7 folder permissions so that I can access the files from either Win7 or Win8?  I assume that taking ownership is the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not even sure if this is feasibly possible to do right and have work smoothly, unless I don't fully understand what you want to do. I can access Win8 user files from Win7 and visa versa but as soon as one puts a password on either account in either OS, the user files will no longer be able to be accessed from the other. I assume you have a password set on at least one of the log-in accounts.

Answer (score -1):

if security please use the security tab and change the permission for your folders. This can be done by right click the drive you want and then properties there select security and assign permissions.